# How to allow multiple inputs from user in JOptionPane

Tags: java, return-value, joptionpane

Before I attempted to insert the Array the code was returning indivdual values for the year input but I would prefer if i could input a list and then display the list if it is a leap year. if it is not it should ignore it. I've not used arrays with JOptionPane... in actual fact I've never used arrays as this is my 4th week using java so I'm quite noobish. but definitely willing to take criticism and advice. I want to get better. Thanks in advance.

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SimpleMath {

```
public static int printLeap(int r, int k){  
    if((r % 4 == 0) && (r % 100 != 0) || (r % 400 == 0)){
    return r;
    }
    else if ((r % 4 != 0) && (r % 100 == 0) || (r % 400 != 0));
    return k;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {


    while (true) { //while the statement is true (so it continues indefinitely until the break occurs).

        String year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter input years to be tested, when done type End");
        int year[] = new year[10];
        for (int x=0; x<year.length; x++)
        if ("End".equals(year)){ //if the user types End then the loop will break. it allows a string to be input for an int value

            break;
        }   {
              int r = Integer.parseInt(year); 

 int k = 0;
int i = printLeap(r, k);
if (i == 0) {
    break; // or System.out.println("");
}
else

    System.out.println("Leap years entered are:  " + i + x);    


}
}
}
```

}

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the basics then move onto GUI components.

Comment: Why not just accept a comma separated list of years and use [`String.split(",")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to create an array from that?

Answer (score 1):

So let's begin with some general code review items:

1. The code is not formatted well, which makes it hard to read. Fixing the indentation goes a long way toward making it readable for others.
2. The `printLeap` method accepts a parameter that you have called `k`. When you call your method you pass it the value 0 because you have initialized `k` to 0 and it never changes. So this forces me to ask - why is `k` a parameter if it never changes?
3. You have syntax errors in your code. This line: `int year[] = new year[10];` is wrong - it should be written `int[] year = new int[10];` but when this is fixed it creates a whole new problem which is duplicate variables. The array you declared conflicts with the `String` above: `String year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);`
4. Later on in the code you try to parse the `year` as an integer, which you can't do because `Integer.parseInt(...)` takes a `String` as a parameter not an array.
5. Variable names are too short and have no meaning. Variables with single character names like `r`, `k`, `i` are in most situations not a good idea. In general the only time it's considered acceptable to use a single character name for a variable is inside of a `for` loop definition like: `for(int i=0; i<10; i++)` because this is such a common pattern.

As for your question, it's not entirely clear what you're really asking here. It sounds like you want to accept a list of years as an input and output the years that are leap years.

So I'll help you get started by providing the following code:

```
//Accept input from the user - a single String containing multiple years separated by commas.
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter years to be tested (comma separated): ");
//Split the String by commas and store the resulting individual years in an array
String[] yearArray = input.split(",");

//Process each year in the array
for(String year: yearArray){
    int intYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
    System.out.println("Here's the integer value: " + intYear);
    //Do more logic here...
}
```

Hope this helps!